# Yum updatesand work arounds using Puppet

Tags: project-management, puppet

I am using Puppet to to ensure quality control for a project and need to run yum updates at the end to verify that everything is up-to-date at the end of the process. It seems like you could use `Class {"yum"}` or `exec { "yum update"}` to start the initial process but my main concern is after finding updates how do you go about accepting the updates and finishing the install.

Thoughts/examples on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

exec { 'yum -y update': }

Sometimes... things are actually simple... :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to be running a global yum update? The point of puppet is to guarantee a machine has a particular state, if you're using it just to always have it install the latest and greatest, than not only is Puppet the wrong tool, there are far easier ways to accomplish that.

Comment: I figured it out, and as the the global config, it is used as a quality control script and we decided against puppet in this particular case.  thank you though!